# websocket api - image encoding yields no image type on client side

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, bufferedimage, java-websocket

I have a web socket server on tomcat 8 with the following binary use:

```
sess.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(bf);
```

where bf is a simple image to bytes conversion as follows:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(...);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write( img, "png", baos );
ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.wrap(baos.toByteArray());
```

this code ends up in the the client side (javascript) as a blob and eventually rendered as an image in the browser and this seems to work just fine.
the only thing that's strange is the the image is rendered typeless as:
data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA......== without the type (image/png).
if I use online encoders for the same image I will get:
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA......==  (notice the image/png type)

and so my question is why is that?
is my image to byte conversion wrong? like I said, the image is displayed fine it just is missing the type.
Note that the data send from the java websocket server is not encoded with base 64, its something I do on the client side (via JS's FileReader.readAsDataURL(blob) - very common).

thanks a lot and sorry for the long post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your image to byte array conversion is not wrong. Byte array conversion treats the images as a binary stream, it has nothing to do with the `MediaType` contained in it.

The type that you want to see is a [Data URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) media type.
Normal java code for converting files to byte array won't give you `data URL scheme` compliant URL.

From the RFC

> data:[<mediatype>][;base64],
>
> The <mediatype> is an Internet media type specification (with
> optional parameters.) The appearance of ";base64" means that the data
> is encoded as base64. Without ";base64", the data (as a sequence of
> octets) is represented using ASCII encoding for octets inside the
> range of safe URL characters and using the standard %xx hex encoding
> of URLs for octets outside that range.  If <mediatype> is omitted, it
> defaults to text/plain;charset=US-ASCII.  As a shorthand,
> "text/plain" can be omitted but the charset parameter supplied.

[RFC source](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397)

When you're creating the `Blob` object in Javascript you have an option to pass `MediaType` to it so that when you read it using `FileReader.readAsDataURL` it fills the appropriate media type.

Example is below

```
var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
```

[Source](https://jsfiddle.net/Jan_Miksovsky/yy7Zs/)

You probably don't need `BufferedImage` in your code, simple file read should suffice.

Following is equivalent of your code with [Apache FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToByteArray(java.io.File)).

```
ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.wrap(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray('test.jpg'));
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the elaborate and quick response. the blob comes out in the client side of the websocket and inspecting this blob has no media type there... so I cant determine on the client side whats the media type... I guess I should simply not use binary, I will use json string on the java server side and add a type property plus encode in base 64 the byte array in another property. this is the only solution I can think off. thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, yes that seems to be a better way or may be you can create the Data URL string at server with the appropriate mediatype.